# Jquery UI Slider - basic example not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

The following simple jquery slider web page using CDNs for the CSS and javascript - displays the slider but does not operate (doesn't step along with mouse clicks). Any ideas anyone?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#slider").slider();
                });
            </script>

            <div id="slider"></div>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery UI CDNs path

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code and it works fine.

```
      < link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

      < script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      < script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```